# I have 3 tables that works on three seperate button.i want to show the default table1 when first loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

But problem is that when I refresh the page without clicking any button, 3 tables shows right next to each other. I want to show the table 1 when the page first loads.
Here is the html part-->

```js
<div class="tab">
  <button id="table1" class="tablinks">Additional Details</button>
  <button id="table2" class="tablinks">User &amp; Application</button>
  <button id="table3" class="tablinks">Specifications</button>
</div>
<div id="Table1" class="tabcontent">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="Table2" class="tabcontent">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>riyad</td>
      <td>zaigirdar</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>arman</td>
      <td>hosain</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="Table3" class="tabcontent">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>onni</td>
      <td>Zaigirdar</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>emu</td>
      <td>rahman</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery part. Even i prefer doing vanilla js. If You can do it with Vanilla js, I will truly appreciate that.->

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table1").click(function(){
    $("#Table2").hide();
     $("#Table3").hide();
    $("#Table1").show();
  });
  $("#table2").click(function(){
    $("#Table1").hide();
    $("#Table3").hide();
    $("#Table2").show();
  });
  $("#table3").click(function(){
    $("#Table1").hide();
    $("#Table2").hide();
    $("#Table3").show();
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee that tables 2 and 3 aren't visible on load, change the static HTML to set them invisible:

```html
<div id="Table1" class="tabcontent" style="display:table">

<div id="Table2" class="tabcontent" style="display:none">

<div id="Table3" class="tabcontent" style="display:none">
```

The alternative is to run some JavaScript to hide them when the page loads, but that can cause flickering of the display.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this one.
here is the vanilla js version of it.
You can as well ditch jQuery.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var table1 = document.querySelector('#Table1');
  var table2 = document.querySelector('#Table2');
  var table3 = document.querySelector('#Table3');
  
  var hide_1_2 = function(){
    table3.style.display = 'table';
    table1.style.display = 'none';
    table2.style.display = 'none';
  }
  var hide_1_3 = function(){
    table2.style.display = 'table';
    table1.style.display = 'none';
    table3.style.display = 'none';
  }
  var hide_2_3 = function(){
    table1.style.display = 'table';
    table2.style.display = 'none';
    table3.style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.querySelector('#table1').addEventListener('click', hide_2_3);
  document.querySelector('#table2').addEventListener('click', hide_1_3);
  document.querySelector('#table3').addEventListener('click', hide_1_2);
})
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button id="table1" class="tablinks">Additional Details</button>
  <button id="table2" class="tablinks">User &amp; Application</button>
  <button id="table3" class="tablinks">Specifications</button>
</div>

<div id="Table1" class="tabcontent">
  <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="Table2" class="tabcontent" style='display:none'>
  <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>riyad</td>
  <td>zaigirdar</td>
  <td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>arman</td>
  <td>hosain</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="Table3" class="tabcontent" style='display:none'>
  <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>onni</td>
  <td>Zaigirdar</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>emu</td>
  <td>rahman</td>
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```